# How can I make my error be posted within my reserved section?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

In the reserved area I wish to show errors that will show up if something doesn't go right with input. One prerequisite I have is that there must be some value within first name. If there is no value, within reserved should show "Name must be filled out". 
[image]

As of right now I have an alert that shows up if the name is not filled out.
[image]

How can I make my errors be posted within the "Reserved" section?

JS:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x = document.forms["application"]["fName"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "")
    {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>int222_162d16 - Assignment 3 - Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"   type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sitecss.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <script src='javascript/myscript.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="application" id="application" method="post" action="https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~emile.ohan/cgi-bin/cardApplication.cgi" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <fieldset>
        <legend class="t"><img src="https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~emile.ohan/int222/bank-logo.png" alt="Assignment #3" />Seneca Bank - Credit Card Application</legend>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <aside class="l"> 
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Primary Applicant's Information</legend>

            <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>First Name*</td>    
                  <td><input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" size="20" maxlength="20" autofocus="autofocus" ></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Surname*</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="sName" id="sName" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Date of Birth*</td>    
                  <td><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" size="10" placeholder="MMMYYYY" maxlength="7"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Email Address*</td>    
                  <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" maxlength="60"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Phone No.*</td>    
                  <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="20" maxlength="12"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
            </aside>

            <section class="s">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Primary Applicant's Address</legend>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Home Address*</td>
                    <td>Apt.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" maxlength="60"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apt" id="apt" size="5" maxlength="4"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><br />City* </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="20" maxlength="40">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><br />Province*</td>
                    <td><br />Postal Code</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="province" name="province" size="2">
                            <optgroup label="Province">
                                <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                                <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
                                <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                                <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
                                <option value="Newfoundland & Labrador">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
                                <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
                                <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                                <option value="Prince Edward Island">PE</option>
                                <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
                                <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="Territory">
                                <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
                                <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
                                <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" size="8" maxlength="7" placeholder="ANA NAN">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
            </section>

            <aside class="r">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Housing Status</legend>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Do you:</td>
                    <td>$Monthly Payment*  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="hStatus" id="s01" value="Own" />Own the property</td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="payment" id="payment" size="8" maxlength="6"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="hStatus" id="s02" value="Rent" />Rent the property</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monthly Income*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="income" id="income" size="8" maxlength="6"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Years at current location*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="currYears" id="currYears" size="3" maxlength="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pre-authorized Code*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="preCode" id="preCode" size="8"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
            </aside>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <section class="s">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Reserved - See below</legend>
                    <p><b>If you submit your application with errors and/or omissions, a list of errors and/or omissions will show here. Make the corrections and re-submit.</b></p>
                    <p><b>If you continue to have a problem submitting your application, make a note of the Reference No. and call us at 1-800-010-2000.</b></p>

                    <script>document.write</script>
                </fieldset>
            </section>

            <aside class="l">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Credit Check / Email Consent</legend>
                <p><b>I consent to have a credit check performed</b></p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="BoxCheck" name="creditCheck" id="c01" value="Yes" onclick="check(this);" />Yes
                <input type="checkbox" class="BoxCheck" name="creditCheck" id="c02" value="No"  onclick= "check(this);" />No
                <br />                                         

                <p><b>I consent to have email messages sent to me</b></p>
                <input type="radio" name="emailConsent" id="m01" value="Yes" />Yes
                <input type="radio" name="emailConsent" id="m02" value="No" />No
                <br />                                         
                Submitted on:

                <script>
                    var d = new Date();
                    document.write(d.toDateString());
                </script>

                &ensp; &ensp; Ref. #                    <input type="text" name="refNo" id="refNo" size="8" readonly="readonly"> <br />
                <!--Submit Application--> <input type="submit" value="Submit Application">
                <!--Start Over-->         <input type="reset" value="Start Over">
                                          <input type="hidden" name="hName" id="hName" value="Mahmood"> <br />
                                          <input type="hidden" name="hId" id="hId" value="int222_162d16"> <br />
            </fieldset>
            </aside>

          </div>



        </fieldset>
        </form>


        <footer class=f>
            <a href="../">My zenit Account</a>   <a href="javascript/">My JavaScript</a>   <a href="css/">My CSS</a>   <a href="honesty.html">My Honesty</a> 
            <script>
                var dt=new Date(document.lastModified);   // Get document last modified date
                document.write('<p>This page was last updated on '+dt.toLocaleString()) + '</p>';
            </script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you use HTML5 I recommend the Javascript Constraint Validation API and required and pattern attributes for the input elements. The Constraint Validation API ist native HTML5 / Javascript. With the API you can react and display all errors where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Option 1:
  You can use the "required" property on your input.
- Option 2:

1- Create a div with style="display:none" where ever you like in your dom and assign an ID to that div. IE:

```
<div id="err1" style="display:none"></div>
```

2- In your javascript, on error:

```
if (x == null || x == "")
{
    var errDiv = document.getElementById("err1");
    errDiv.innerHTML = "Please fill input";
    errDiv.style.display = 'block';

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, just add a `<span>` element to your `<section class="s">`. Give the span an id like 'err_log' or just 'err' and use this to output the error

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x = document.forms["application"]["fName"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "")
    {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        document.getElementById('youridofthespan').innerHTML='Name must be filled out';
        return false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('youridofthespan').innerHTML='';
    }
}
```

If you want to show and delete multiple errors, you can simply create on span for every error and do above to use them.

Hope this helps :)